# Disabling Some Jackson Serializing Efficiency

Tags: json, serialization, spring-boot, jackson

I have an Entity with four `@OneToOne` mappings to the same Entity:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = TaxTable.class)
public class TaxTable extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView({Views.Summary.class, Views.Detailed.class})
    private TaxRate taxRate1;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView({Views.Summary.class, Views.Detailed.class})
    private TaxRate taxRate2;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView({Views.Summary.class, Views.Detailed.class})
    private TaxRate taxRate3;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonView({Views.Summary.class, Views.Detailed.class})
    private TaxRate taxRate4;
}
```

When I retrieve the TaxTable from my controller, I get the following:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "taxRate1": {
    "id": 1,
    // more properties here
  },
  "taxRate2": 1,
  "taxRate3": 1,
  "taxRate4": 1
}
```

This is happening because they all reference the same object. But is there a way to tell Jackson not to be so efficient? I was looking through the [SerlizationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html) but can't find anything specific about this.

Comment: "tell Jackson not to be so efficient". Can you elaborate on this statement?

Comment: I want taxRate1-4 to all have that full TaxRate object. As I said in my question, since they are all the same object, Jackson is only giving me the full object once. Which is generally helpful, but in my current use case, I don't want that to happen.